# HTML and CSS won't link

Tags: html, css

My html and css won't link the css is suppose to make the Hayes and Ash words red on the header. My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="background-color:#FFA100;>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Documents and Settings\Test.DOBRUSKY\Desktop\stylesheet.css"/>
    <title>Hayes and Ash</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hayes and Ash<h1>
    <div id="hayes">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/xXSDVAm.jpg?1"/>
        <p>I am Hayes harharhar</p>
    </div>
    <div id="ash">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/zcBLpU6.jpg?1"/>
        <p>This is Ash I am very fluffy!</p>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check Google for the proper syntax for a link tag, and check the path to your CSS file while you're at it.

Comment: Try inspect element and see if your resource have css file.
 Try use css code directly in html and check if it work.

Answer (score 4):

The href link:

```
href="C:\Documents and Settings\Test.DOBRUSKY\Desktop\stylesheet.css"
```

should be a *URL*, not a local file system path.  And it can be relative to the location of the HTML document, such as:

```
href="stylesheet.css"
```

or

```
href="http://www.example.com/somewhere/out/there/stylesheet.css"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
```

Link the css file this way as show above and check it also

Close the h1 tag

```
<h1> Hayes and Ash </h1>
```

The color may be applied to all the text in the body.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a direct reference to your local computer in your link statement.
C:\Documents and Settings\Test.DOBRUSKY\Desktop\stylesheet.css

The best practice is to put your style sheets in a folder inside your project, then reference the style sheet there. Your href reference would look like this if you put your style sheet in a folder named "styles".
href="~\styles\stylesheet.css"

You can of course put your stylesheet inside your project's main folder if you want but it's nice to have the folder structure for adding more css files to your project.

Check out Method 3 in the following article. 
http://html.net/tutorials/css/lesson2.php

Answer (score 0):

That same problem happened to me two days ago.

I tried many different ways to type in the src. None of them worked. Double checked them and triple checked them, in case of missing character or typo error.

Finally, the problem I found was that I created the directories and files with powershell. CSS file had no issue, but the html file didn't like to be created from the powershell (I don't know the reason for that) (that problem didn't occur using the terminal at Macbookpro). So I opened a notepad, and pasted the exact same code from the previous file (the one created using echo command at powershell), saved it as .html and then, the css file linked with the html and styled it just fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).